# Android studio library project

Tags: android, android-library, android-studio, gradle

У меня есть проект библиотеки. Экспортируется он как .aar файл (новомодный формат библиотек. Градл, наверно, может и обычный jar сбилдить, но мне подходит и так).  
Зависит проект от нескольких библиотек, например, таких:

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
 compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
 compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
```

Вопрос: Как мне включить эти зависимости в результирующий aar файл? После компиляции в aar находятся только мои классы, а мне надо, чтобы там находились все.

Сразу напишу, зачем мне это нужно:  
Мне, по сути, нужно взять все скомпилированные классы (.class), и сделать из них .dex, который будет динамически подключаться к приложению во время выполнения. Это позволяет обновлять исполняемый код без обновления APK файла.

Comment: > Это позволяет обновлять исполняемый код без обновления APK файла.

Только учтите, что это будет работать лишь с Dalvik, ART ломает всю вашу идею на корню. Да и с Dalvik'ом теряется возможность использовать odex, то есть вы лишаете ОС возможности оптимизировать байт-код вашего приложения. Имхо, делать так не стоит.

Comment: @falstaf, без вариантов. Отказаться от таких обновлений не представляется возможным. Приложение для корпоративных клиентов, которые "вращали мои обновления на барабане". На их дивайсах даже google play не установлен, и устанавливать APK для каждого обновления они не станут.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему следующим извращенным образом:  
Создал такую таску в `build.gradle`

```
task copyDependencies() {
    doLast {
        copy {
            configurations.getByName("_release").each {
                from(it.absoluteFile.parent)
                into('build/toBeDexed')
                include(it.absoluteFile.name)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

То есть копирую все зависимости нужной мне конфигурации в папку, потом копирую туда же свой `classes.jar`, и обрабатываю DX'ом.